# Linux - how to start a daemon process without logging in

Tags: linux, windows

I initially did this in Between Windows machines. where

1) I logged on to a data server.

2) Using PSEXEC I executed the remote batch scripts to m1, m2, and m3

`psexec \\ComputerName script_location_in_that_computer`

3) m1, m2, and m3 are all Windows machines.

Now, I have to repeat the above where m1, m2, m3 are actually Linux (Ubuntu 16.04 LTS) boxes! I know that I can use the following (provided that putty is installed):

`plink -i key_location username@machineaddress.com "command string"`

Is there any way I can simply execute the scripts without keys/password?

I believe the answer is "NO" - because in Windows I executed that as the AD user (logged in user) - so in Linux I need either authroized_keys or some credential to verify who is executing it. But if there is a better way to do it, I would like to know.

Comment: You want any machine on the network to be able to run commands unauthenticated on this machine?

Comment: actually not any network. The machines are within the same domain, and doesn't communicate with outside world (blocked by strict firewall rules). It's something like a remote start of 2-3 daemon process without actually logging into each and every one of them...something like a bootstrap script